# Preferred DNS server: Router or ISP

Tags: router, dns

I'm making my computer have a static IP address so I need to set a DNS server, should I set the Preferred DNS server setting on my computer to the IP of my router, or should I set it to the IP of my ISPs DNS server?

Basically should I go through the router or directly to the DNS server?

Comment: IF you're manually setting your dns settings, why not just set it to google's dns (8.8.8.8 & 8.8.4.4) or open dns

Comment: I'm just testing that now, though I'm not testing OpenDNS, I've used it before and it requires accounts, and i don't like it much. Will OpenDNS be better than Google?

Comment: OpenDNS does not require an account. You can just use the IP addresses.

Comment: oh, will it be better than google though?

Comment: If by *better* you mean faster, that is very dependent on your connection and proximity to servers.  I've used both services and they're both very good, however to get the **fastest** you will need to do the testing yourself.

Comment: Warning, OpenDNS is a lying DNS resolver: it modifies the responses from the legitimate name servers.

Comment: Yes, i agree with @bortzmeyer... I would suggest to use google as a first preference, as it will not give you a incorrect address if it doesn't find a domain.  Open DNS will give you the IP of one of it's machines when it can't find a domain, this is in an effort to get your browser to go to it's site so it can serve you ads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as the DNS is concerned, it really doesn't matter.  Your router will end up doing the lookup to your ISP anyway.  As for performance, you will likely get better performance using your ISP directly since your router is pretty under-powered and will be relatively slow in responding to queries.  However, in theory, if your router is able to cache queries, if you visit the same domains repeatedly its possible the router will be faster.

You can use a [DNS Benchmark Utility](http://www.grc.com/dns/benchmark.htm) to test both options and decide for yourself.

Comment: Or this benchmark utility: http://code.google.com/p/namebench/

Comment: The router does not necessarily forward to the ISP nameserver. It can be fully recursive just by itself.

Answer (score 4):

Most low-grade CPE routers are very bad with DNS proxying. It is highly recommended to bypass them and to talk directly to the ISP.

See [a survey by the swedish registry](http://www.iis.se/docs/Routertester_en.pdf) and one [by ICANN SSAC](http://www.icann.org/committees/security/sac035.pdf). Both surveys were made in the context of DNSSEC but apply to far wider issues.

And [RFC 5625](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5625.txt) for advices to the routers programmers (of course, not one of them have read a RFC).